# Google Translator adds markup that affects my layout

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the google translator code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
   </script>
```

I'm changing the website language English to Arabic. The code works, but adds markup which changes the layout unexpectedly.

Before translation:

[image: Image before translation]

After translation:
[image: Image after translation]

Here is html code before translation:

```
  <div class="pcss3t pcss3t-effect-slide-bottom pcss3t-theme-4">
    <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" checked="" id="tab1" class="tab-content-1">
    <label for="tab1">Events</label>
    <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab2" class="tab-content-2">
    <label for="tab2">In the News</label>
    <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab3" class="tab-content-3">
    <label for="tab3">Press Releases</label>
    <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab4" class="tab-content-4">
    <label for="tab4">Speeches</label>
      </div>
```

Here is html code after translation. Google translator added some extra html elements:

```
 <div class="pcss3t pcss3t-effect-slide-bottom pcss3t-theme-4">
    <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" checked="" id="tab1" class="tab-content-1">
    <label for="tab1">
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">أحداث </font></font></label>
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><label for="tab2">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">في الأخبار </font>
        </label>
        <label for="tab3"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">الصحفية </font>     </label>
        <label for="tab4"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">الخطابات</font></label>
     </font>
      <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab2" class="tab-content-2">
      <label for="tab2"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"></font></label>
      <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab3" class="tab-content-3">
      <label for="tab3"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"></font></label>
      <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab4" class="tab-content-4">
      <label for="tab4"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"></font>
   </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please properly format your markup.

Comment: ok I just change

Answer (score 3):

Although apparently there are some people working on [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=872770), because it's breaking currently the most popular view library on Earth (React, Jan 2019), there is nothing you can do about it.

But you can always add `notranslate` class to the element which should not be touched by Google Translate, like:

```
<nav class="notranslate">
  (...)
</nav>
```

Maybe that will help you somewhat.

Comment: It does not work: "notranslate" prevents Google translate to translate the text inside the element but does not prevent to change the href attribute in anchor, which breaks the Bootstrap tab mechanism.